# Adding field to PostGIS Layer with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I'm having trouble adding a field to a PostGIS table using PyQGIS. Here's my code:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
from qgis.core import *

inLayer = iface.activeLayer()
provider = inLayer.dataProvider()

# add field
field = QgsField('test_field', QVariant.String)
inLayer.startEditing()
provider.addAttributes([field])
inLayer.updateFields()

# commit
inLayer.commitChanges()
```

The commit fails and the PostGIS log shows an error:

> 2015-10-27T08:13:28    1   Erroneous query: ALTER TABLE "received"."env" ADD COLUMN "test_field"  returned 7 [ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
>
> LINE 1: ALTER TABLE "received"."env" ADD COLUMN "test_field"

Seems the call to PostGIS fails to include the column type. Is this a bug, or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 3):

If you need to add a new column in your layer from Postgis, use this:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

name_column = "new_column"

layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField(name_column, QVariant.String, "VARCHAR")])
layer.updateFields()
```

Comment: Please avoid duplicate answers: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/326197/8104

Comment: @bugmenot123 The duplicate answer that I linked was deleted. Are you referring to the accepted answer in the linked thread?